# the values of coordinates in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, coordinates

if i have the matrix

```
s = [ 0         0.4000    0.5000    0.6000    0.9000
      0.4000         0    0.3000    0.4000    0.5000
      0.5000    0.3000         0    0.5000    0.8000
      0.6000    0.4000    0.5000         0    0.6000
      0.9000    0.5000    0.8000    0.6000         0];
```

and

```
coordinates = [1 2; 1 3; 2 4]
```

then i want that the values of previous coordinates equal zero. i.e s(1,2),s(2,1),s(1,3)s(3,1),s(2,4),s(4,2) equal 0 i.e i want this result

```
0         0         0         0.6000    0.9000
0         0         0.3000    0         0.5000
0         0.3000         0    0.5000    0.8000
0.6000    0         0.5000         0    0.6000
0.9000    0.5000    0.8000    0.6000         0`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be what you want. You only need to use [`sub2ind`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html):

```
s(sub2ind(size(s), coordinates(:,1), coordinates(:,2))) = 0; %// make these entries 0
s(sub2ind(size(s), coordinates(:,2), coordinates(:,1))) = 0; %// and symmetric entries too
```